# Trouble configuring NetBeans 6.9 with MinGW GCC 4.5.0

Tags: c++, c, gcc, netbeans, mingw

I recently installed NetBeans (and configured it to work with MinGW) following this directions: http://netbeans.org/community/releases/69/cpp-setup-instructions.html. Those direction  gave me direct link to MinGW GCC tools which are older version ( 3.4.5 ) So I updated MinGW to 4.5.0 version and now I can't compile C/C++ projects. I installed mingw from cmd.exe with this command:
mingw-get install gcc g++ fortran objc ada gdb msys-base

I'll put some photos:
What have I forgot to do?
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**

### EDIT

**
Now netbeans found stdio.h directory but gave me this error
[image]

**SOLVED**
Just needed to install older version of msys make in saparate directory

## [image]

Comment: have you tried restarting Netbeans? I'm pretty sure I had the same problem and after I restarted it, it worked fine.

Comment: yes i tried,... someting is wrong with paths because netbeans says that it cannot find <stdio.h> although i included mingw directorys (see pictures )

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with *newer* version. Maybe if you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224381/mingw-netbeans-6-9-1-problem) you can solve your probem(although could be less elegant).

Answer (score -1):

Could you please post which version/dir ? I have the same problem

EDIT : and the answer is :[image]

what I did was delete c:\mingw - rerun mingw-get-inst-20101030.exe - did not select the Msys build (it says not usually installed) - run MSYS-1.0.11.exe (the *older version* I guess) - changed the path in netbeans (screen above) - built

EDIT2 : I made a [detailed post](http://udunslabs.blogspot.com/2011/03/netbeans-mingw-c.html)

Comment: have you noticed my answer is 7 months old and addresses the OP - while Wall-e's is 10 days old ?