# MingW Netbeans 6.9.1 problem

Tags: c++, c, mingw, netbeans-6.9

I have one problem with MingW(mingw-get-inst-20110211) and Netbeans 6.9.1. I installed MingW and add it to Netbeans without problem, but when I try to run one simple cpp app, throws this error

> mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows
>   make[2]: mkdir: Command not found
>   make[2]: [build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o] Error 127
>   make[1]: [.build-conf] Error 2
>   make: [.build-impl] Error 2
>   make[2]: Leaving directory '/c/Documents and Settings/Marco/My Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
>   make[1]: Leaving directory '/c/Documents and Settings/Marco/My Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
>   BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 1s)

I already write "path", MingW it's installed on "C:\MingW".

Hope someone can tell what's wrong or what I forgot to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's was kind of messy but finally get a way.

1° Install [MinGW](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Automated%20MinGW%20Installer/mingw-get-inst/mingw-get-inst-20110211/mingw-get-inst-20110211.exe/download) (C/C++ en my particular case)

2° Install [MSYS](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/mingw/MSYS-1.0.10.exe) (Answer two or three question at the end of installation, refering where MinGW is installed)

3° Add to Netbeans(Tools>Options>C/C++) the "\MinGW\bin" adress. It should look like this

[image]

It should be it regarding installation, but when a new project is created you should add  [this library](http://pt.sourceforge.jp/projects/sfnet_openmarias/downloads/libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll/) to the project folder, it seems to be a problem with dynamic compile(I don't really know the problem but this should fix it).

That's all.

Comment: Sounds a lot like what I advised you. If my answer was helpful, you should go ahead and vote it.

Comment: I have a detailed guide [here](http://udunslabs.blogspot.com/2011/03/netbeans-mingw-c.html)

Answer (score 3):

You should add C:\msys\1.0\bin to your system path and restart the IDE. 
It should solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

follow this guide as making MinGW work under Netbeans requires an additional couple of steps (specifically MSYS' make).

http://netbeans.org/community/releases/68/cpp-setup-instructions.html#mingw

**Edit**:

Make sure the correct executables are specified in the Toolchain (Tools -> Options -> C/C++).

Comment: I think this version installs MSYS and I tried that guide but every link to "how to" is broken

Comment: If you did install MinGW and MSYS' make correctly, make sure the correct executable is specified in the Toolchain (Tools, Options, C/C++). I did an installation of Netbeans 6.9.1 with MinGW few days ago and following that guide, everything worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Add `C:\msys\1.0\bin` to Windows system path, and please add it at the beginning.

I got the same error when I add it to the tail of the path, then I add it at the beginning, it worked!