# Netbeans C++ MinGW settings

Tags: c++, netbeans, mingw

I've installeed Netbeans 7.0.1 and MinGW on my computer, but when I tried to build a project, it shows the error message:
[image]

I googled the problem, and every solution said that I need to add MYSY to Path, so I did it; and restarted netbeans, but the problem still shows up, I'm thinking about maybe it's because I installed Qt4.7.4 so there maybe some conflicts in %Path%,

here is the two Paths in my computer:

**User variables for shengy:**

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\Common\Tools\WinNT;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\Common\MSDev98\Bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\Common\Tools;C:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   Visual Studio\VC98\bin;C:\Program Files\IDM Computer
>   Solutions\UltraEdit\;C:\boost_1_34_1;C:\Program
>   Files\Telelogic\Telelogic Synergy 6.5\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Telelogic\Telelogic Synergy 6.5\lib;

**System variables:**

> C:\Perl\bin\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program
>   Files\doxygen\bin;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program
>   Files\COSMIC\CXS12X;C:\COSMIC\CX12;C:\Program Files\PC Connectivity
>   Solution\;C:\shengy\ComplieCommands;C:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\mingw\lib;C:\Program
>   Files\Telelogic\Telelogic Synergy
>   6.5\bin;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin;C:\MinGW\bin;

please help me about this. Thanks

Comment: Are you using proper make tool from MinSys instead of broken one from MinGW?

Answer (score 3):

make shure you have set the correct tool collection for mingw (**`options -> C/C++ -> Build tools`**, **`Base directory:`** `C:\MinGW\bin`).

All compilers / commands (excluding `make` / `qmake`) should point to there too.

Also make shure ...

- you can run `mkdir` from `cmd`
- if qt ships its own MinGW: you use yours (maybe you can remove the one from qt)
- move the `path` variables from mingw *before* the one from qt

See:

- [MinGW Compilers and Tools](http://netbeans.org/community/releases/68/cpp-setup-instructions.html#mingw)
- [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5227169/1622894)

**edit:** does `C:\shengy\ComplieCommands` contain any mingw / gcc programs?

Answer (score 1):

i had a problem like it. i think you should install MYSY (as you did) and then adjust netbeans like below:
**tools->c/c++ -> build tools -> make command** set to **mysys\bin\make.exe**